# Order of operations when using <AND> and <OR > in a boolean search on Twitter

Tags: twitter, search

How does Twitter search interpret the order of boolean operators?

Does it support parentheses for clarifying the order of Boolean operators?

If one does a search like

```
A AND B OR C AND D
```

what does Twitter actually search?

```
1: A AND (B OR (C AND D)) ?
```

or

```
2: (A AND B) OR (C AND D) ?
```

or

```
3: A AND (B OR C) AND D ?
```

or

```
4: ((A AND B) OR C) AND D ?
```

or something else?

---

I can now confirm that the answer of @w3d is correct, i.e., if you so a search like

```
A B OR C D OR E F
```

it is actually interpreted as

```
(A AND B) OR (C AND D) OR (E AND F)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it support parentheses for clarifying the order of Boolean operators?

It does appear to, although I've not found anything in the help docs to support this.

> If one does a search like A AND B OR C AND D

`OR` appears to have a higher precedence than `AND` (which I'm not even sure is an operator - see below), so this would seem to be equivalent to your  #3:

3: `A AND (B OR C) AND D`

And this returns the same (or very *similar*) results for me. Placing the parentheses differently returns very different results. I say "similar", because... (and this is an assumption) including parenthesis occasionally returns *marginally* different results, but I have put this down to the very dynamic nature of Twitter searches. Searching for the same phrase just minutes apart can return different results and then a few minutes later the same results again. (?)

However, as mentioned, I'm not convinced that `AND` is actually an operator. "and" is the default operator when words are separated by a space. There is no mention of an `AND` operator on the [Twitter Advanced Search](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-using-advanced-search) Help page. And omitting `AND` yields the same results. It is quite possible that "AND" is simply stripped from the search phrase as being a "common" word. `A AND B OR C AND D` is equivalent to `A B OR C D`

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It is true that writing an SPACE
is like putting an <AND>. So this operator exists but as you mentioned
it is implicit.
What you said about the precedence of <OR> with respect to <AND> is
very interesting. I was so surprised that I could not find anything
about this on the web. About putting parenthesis I am confused,
it seems that putting parentheses sometimes has no
effect.

Comment: "precedence of <OR> with respect to <AND> is very interesting." - yes, this is perhaps the opposite to what you might expect (in most programming languages "AND" will take precedence over "OR"). "putting parentheses sometimes has no effect" - this will depend on whether the parentheses changes the natural precedence of the operators. There may also be a "nesting" limit that we are unaware of (does it even support _nested_ parentheses?).

Answer (score 2):

```
social media metrics OR analytics
```

The `OR` operator will attach to the word that immediately precedes it, very much like order of operations in algebra. For example, the above query will find tweets that mention *social media metrics* or *social media analytics*, because the `OR` links to the *metrics* and *analytics* terms. [+](https://unionmetrics.com/resources/how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search-queries/)